# Windows 7 won't boot from one hard disk with another hard disk connected containing another windows 7 installation

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, hard-drive, boot, partitioning

I tried to shrink a partition(not C: drive) from ubuntu using gparted so that I can allocate more space to C:. After the shrinking, Windows 7 won't boot. The grub screen shows up(dual boot win7 and ubuntu) and when I select windows it hangs at 'starting windows' screen. The other options don't work as well.. safe mode/repair etc.
Trying to access the drive I was trying to shrinkfrom ubuntu says I need to run CHKDSK /f on it from windows.But I can access the C: partition from ubuntu fine.

I connect this hard disk to another working windows computer, boot from the hard drive that has the working windows, and it gets stuck at 'starting windows' screen. I remove the hard disk with the bad windows installation, it boots fine. But with the bad windows hard drive it just doesn't boot. And it is not a device selection issue as the grub screen doesn't show up and it goes straight to starting windows screen. So the working windows is trying to boot. But it fails.

I got a windows 7 CD and made a bootable usb flash drive with it. Booted from them. They boot, but when I enter system repair, it gets stuck at 'System Restore options' screen where it detects the partition with the faulty windows but I can't click next or anything.

What I need is not even in the C:. it is in the partition next to C: that I tried to shrink. It has some 200 gigs of non backed up music. Is there any way I can get it back? Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect your hard disk to another computer as an external hard drive and open dive C or any drive that you had you document and just copy everything to the other computer and when you are than just re install windows but this time do it a clean installation.
WAY to connect your hard disk as external.
If you have an external hard drive.
First open your hard drive 
Second take out the front part of hard drive that connects hard drive to the cable.
when you take out the front part. take the front part and connect it to your hard disk and use the USB cable to connect to your computer.
Or just open your computer take out hard disk and open up the other computer and connect you hard disk.
**Do not connect the hard disk to other computer as a primary hard drive**.

Comment: I don't have the kind of external hard drive I think you are talking about. What do you mean by primary hard drive? I am not booting from the faulty windows hard drive.

Comment: Don't you want your Music back.

Comment: And you said that you can not run the windows so just get your files and re-install your windows.

Comment: Maybe I am not getting what you are saying. I do not have an external hard drive. What do I need to do exactly? I cannot boot into windows(on different machine) with the hard drive with the faulty windows connected.

Comment: I cannot boot into another computer too with the faulty hard drive connected(to a sata port). Gets stuck at 'starting windows'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18577/discussion-between-thekindlyone-and-mahdi-ahmadi).

Comment: you don't need to boot your hard disk. you just need to connect it to other computer as an external hard disk. with USB cable.or use an ATA cable to connect your hard disk  to your computer. But when you use the cable just connect the bigger one first and when you Turn on your computer and windows came up just connect the bigger cable to your hard disk.

Comment: Okay, that worked, but chkdsk /f E: just hangs.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ak5fD3uLsH0

Comment: Watch the video and do it. and sorry for recording the video up side down.http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-L9hKChPlA8&feature=youtu.be

Comment: it did get detected. All the partitions on the faulty hard drive are accessible except the one with the music. Disk Management halts at 'loading disk configuration information'. Chkdsk doesn't respond on that drive too.